# Run methods in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a program that, among other things, parses some big files, and I would like to have this done in parallel to save time.
The code flow looks something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = program_object()
    obj.do_so_some_stuff(argv)
    obj.field1 = parse_file_one(f1)
    obj.field2 = parse_file_two(f2)
    obj.do_some_more_stuff()
```

I tried running the file parsing methods in separate processes like this:

```
p_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=parse_file_one, args=(f1))
p_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=parse_file_two, args=(f2))
p_1.start()
p_2.start()
p_1.join()
p_2.join()
```

There are 2 problems here. One is how to have the separate process modify the filed, but more importantly, forking the process duplicates my whole main! I get exception regarding argv when executing the

```
do_so_some_stuff(argv)
```

second time. That really is not what I wanted. It even happened when I run only 1 of the Processes.

How could I get *just* the file parsing methods to run in parallel to each other, and then continue back with main process like before?

Comment: Have you not read this https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/threading.html

Comment: Or this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Is it possible to optimize the stuff that needs to happen, besides doing it in separate threads? What is your 'parse_file_one(f1)'? normally multiprocessing should be a "last option" after everything else has been tried before.

Comment: Those are two xml parsing methods. Each works with different structure of the xml, and then does a lot of different math on the values there. The files are about 100MB each, so this can take significant time when done consecutively. In system I see only 1 core is loaded and 3 are almost idle. I thought if I could run both at same time on separate cores, this should hopefully help.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some different problem with the code that fails? The multiprocessing shouldn't run you main twice.

Comment: It's weird. It behaves as if it clones the entire process. I could work around that by restructuring my code and having main run just the processes. Its ugly but would work. Another problem is that even when I get the multiple processes (and I see them in task manager) they still run on one core, which defeats the whole purpose of tinkering with multiprocessing. It's taking me too much time and effort, so I'll put this project on back burner for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the parsing methods in a separate module.

Answer (score 1):

First, i guess instead of:

```
obj = program_object()
program_object.do_so_some_stuff(argv)
```

you mean:

```
obj = program_object()
obj.do_so_some_stuff(argv)
```

Second, try using threading like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import thread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
       thread.start_new_thread( parse_file_one, (f1) )
       thread.start_new_thread( parse_file_two, (f2) )
    except:
       print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

But, as pointed out by [Wooble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110707/wooble), depending on the implementation of your parsing functions, this might not be a solution that executes truly in parallel, because of the [GIL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock).

In that case, you should check the Python `multiprocessing` module that will do true concurrent execution:

> `multiprocessing` is a package that supports spawning processes using an
>   API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
>   offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping
>   the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.
>   Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully
>   leverage multiple processors on a given machine.

Comment: Because of the GIL, this is unlikely to make things any faster (or to let them happen in parallel). Of course, this depends what the `parse_file_*` methods actually do.

Comment: @first  Yes, that was silly mistake. :) I corrected the post.

Comment: I tried your solution. It spawned 2 additional python processes, and they seem to sit there indefinitely. Original code took ~2min. After waiting over 30min for this, I killed them. Anyway, only 1 core was being used.
I get similar results when using multiprocessing library directly. Only join with timeout seems to put an end to the processes.
I will keep trying and studying the topic, and will post if I find a working solution.